# Github - How to embed a code file in "Markdown"(README.md)?

Tags: html, github, markdown

I know this question may have been answered before, but I've tried various methods, such as `<object>, <embed>, <ifame>`, and none of them work.

I have a README.md and a python file in the same directory on Github, and I was looking for embed the codes from this python file into README.md, is there any method or suggestion?

For the `<object>, <embed>, <ifame>`, I tried using raw url or local path (python.py), not sure is those are the right way to used.

Comment: @pmf Thanks! That's the answer I looking for!

Answer (score -1):

How do you mean embed? If it's just an inline code block, you can use backtick quotes (`).

Comment: No need to copy code from the file, I think (`) and (```) need to copy the code and paste it in.

Comment: @MiKi if I'm understanding what you want, then you can just link to the file like so: ``` [my link](github.com/.../myPythonScript.py)

Comment: Sorry, I try, but that just displays the URL in a code block. What I wanna is to give a link or file path, then displays the contents of this file.

Comment: @MiKi I'm not sure if what you're asking is possible ie using an iframe or something. In markdown files, it's all text. Why is what you're asking for better than either linking to the file or just embedding the code in a block? It seems to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: I have about 50+ directories with the same structure, it would be troublesome to copy and paste the code directly into README.md.